# Convergence of Series, given similar series converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was doing a past paper for which there are no answer and got stumped on this:

Let $a_n$ where $n \in N$ be a sequence of real numbers such that 0 < $a_n$ < 1 for all n.

Prove that, if the series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then the series
$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ converges as well.

I have tried finding bounds for the second series but have not gotten very far, any advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: since the series converges $a_n \to 0$. Use this and the fact that the $a_n$'s are positive. It is enough to bound the tail of the second series.

Comment: If a_n/1-a_n < 2a_n, then since the sum of a_n converges so does 2a_n and so by the comparison test a_n/1-a_n must is that correct?